# Is $P(A\cap B \mid C)=P(A\mid C)\cdot P( B \mid C)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is $P(A\cap B \mid C)=P(A\mid C)\cdot P( B \mid C)$ if $A$  and $B$  are independent?

It seems reasonable enough, but I can't seem to prove it from the definition of conditional probability

Edit: The events $A\mid C$  and $B\mid C$ are the ones that are independent. But does this make any difference?

Comment: If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent then it's true.

Comment: The phrase "The events A∣C and B∣C" is absurd since there are no such things as events A∣C and B∣C, actually, A∣C and B∣C do not exist, period.

Comment: @Did we can think of conditional probability given $C$ as defining a probability measure on $\Omega \cap C$ (if $\Omega$ is the original sample space) and $A\mid C$ and $B \mid C$ will totally be events there. But I agree that this might be too sophisticated a tool given the context.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Nobody does this and there are serious disadvantages to this construction -- but you are not the first one on this site to believe it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independence of $A$ and $C$ means that $P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$.

Conditional probability says that $P(A|C)=\dfrac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}$

So if $A$ and $C$ are independent, $P(A|C)=P(A)$ and you can easily work out that what you're saying is correct if $A,B$ **and** $C$ are all independent but not necessarily for the case you originally asked about.

But what you're asking in your edit is about $A|C$ and $B|C$ being independent which doesn't make any sense in another way than as [conditional independece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of $A$ and $B$ given $C$, and then it's true by definition.

Comment: But $A$ and $C$ are not necessarily independent. All we know is that $(A\mid C) \perp (B\mid C)$

Comment: @H.Rappeport But what does $(A|C)\bot(B|C)$ mean if not $(A\bot B)|C$?

Comment: I was unaware of the notion of Conditional independence. That indeed solves it (And is probably what was meant by the phrasing in the original question). Thank you.

Comment: But **I am** sure, with or without the link you suggested... hence I know with certainty that "interpreting" an absurdity in a question "to the closest thing to make sense" is not helping a lost OP in the least, only furthering their confusion.

Comment: The only thing "subpar" about my answer is that I don't say explicitly that $A|C$ is not an event, and the asker already noted that the formulation they asked about was a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture as originally stated is false. A simple counterexample is as follows.

Let $X,Y,Z,T$ be four mutually independent events each having probability $\frac{1}{4}$. Let $$A=X\cup Y,B=X\cup Z,C=X\cup T $$

Comment: Why $ A,B $ are dependent though?